# How to stop oil separating from cheese

Tags: baking, cheese, pie

I cooked something yesterday similar to a potato Gratin using a cheese sauce. I noticed afterwards that the oil from the cheese had separated and after serving it up, there was a pool of orangey oil sitting on the plate.

Is there a way to prevent this, either by using a certain type of cheese or some other way?

The cheese I used was a mature farmhouse cheddar.

Comment: How are you making the sauce? And there is the problem that, the firmer the cheese, the worse its melting behavior. You might be able to tame it, but it will be more difficult with the aged cheeses.

Comment: I made the sauce by adding the cheese to a Roux. It is fine alone but after baking it separates. The problem is that I need an aged cheese to stop the flavour being bland.

Comment: Isn't that just the MSG at work?

Comment: Is this a [duplicate](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45980/23376), since it's related to making cheese sauce?

Comment: @bonCodigo Just because it's related to making cheese sauce, doesn't automatically make it a duplicate. The question you posted may partly be an answer in itself, like the user below has provided.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are worried about the flavor being bland, but have you tried mixing the aged, dry cheese with one that will melt better? The flavor of a good, mature cheese goes a long way, so I don't think you will notice a loss of flavor... Find a flavorful, relatively young, melty cheese, experiment with the proportions, and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [add some emulsifiers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45980/23376). Or even use processed cheeses (which contain those emulsifiers).